# Ubuntu is using 170 GB of HDD

Tags: disk-usage, free

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 with Gnome (to be more exact it is this onehttps://ubuntugnome.org/) and everything was going perfectly well and I couldn't complain. I installed it on a 194GB partition (Windows 7 is living on a 50 GB partition). The problem is that suddenly Ubuntu is eating up 174 GB out of 194 GB. I did remove the sources of the installed packages (which gave me about 1 GB back). I emptied the trash already and my downloads folder is taking up 8 GB of space. I do appreciate everybody's time on this matter and help.

Thanks!

So I did what my friend said and here we are:

```
$ sudo apt-get clean
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
$ sudo du -sh ~
9,6G    /home/bert
```

According to Disks

```
194 GB — 39 GB free (79,7% full)
```

Comment: Also if my home folder is eating up only 9,6 GB where did the rest of my space go? It went down to 155GB - 9,6 GB = 145,4 GB for the system?

Comment: And I just checked the /var/log folder its eating up 18 MB. I also ran again Disc Analyzer (gksudo baobab) and I have the same results (trying to make this as idiot proof as possible).

Comment: can you provide the output of df -h

Comment: It got fixed witha reboot so now it shows the correct numbers..... But with df -h it also showed 79.7% full I rembmer running that command to see what was going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this :

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Also seeing that your downloads folder is taking up a lot of space, delete everything you don't need in your downloads folder.

See how much disk space the above clears. If not very much, then run :

```
sudo du -sh ~
```

If this number is most of your storage being used, that is **your files** taking up most of your storage. Delete the files you do not need.

Comment: [sudo] password for bert: 
bert@Skyrim:/var/cache$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
bert@Skyrim:/var/cache$ sudo du -sh ~
9,6G /home/bert

Comment: Read initial question fro a better view. and thanks!

Comment: No idea what happened.. rebooted and it showed that I am using 9% suddenly... Appreciate the speed!